# AIR Android GCM ANE MismatchSenderId

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Has anyone been able to get the Android AIR extension http://myappsnippet.com/gcm/ to work? I'm well aware of how to setup GCM. But when using the extension above I can not stop getting the `MismatchSenderId` error.

I've used https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Push-Notification

and it works.

I've also used http://afterisk.wordpress.com/2012/09/22/the-only-free-and-fully-functional-android-gcm-native-extension-for-adobe-air/

and it works.

I've even tried http://myappsnippet.com/gcm/ on a "clean" phone that has never had my app installed, and still get the `MismatchSenderId` error.

If I take the registration ID I get from registering with one of the other extensions then it can be received using the above ANE. But If I use the registration ID from http://myappsnippet.com/gcm/ it gives me the same `MismatchSenderId` error.

Does anyone have any experience with this particular ANE? I followed step by step and looked through the example throughly. I need this one to work because it actually uses icons, sounds, and vibrations on the notify. Not having that essentially makes the other ANEs worthless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is fixed. I have just emailed out the updated .ane to all developers who had a similar problem :) let me know if you're problem is also fixed now?

Comment: Ok it's all working fine for me now in v 2.1 update of the extension. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting a mismatched error from Google, one of the reasons besides what is explained in the comments section of http://myappsnippet.com/gcm/, may be because you have tested some other GCM extensions on your app! you see, if you have already used some other GCM extensions in your app and now you are trying use our extension, Google will throw a mismatched error because your RegId is still cached in Google servers. how can you fix it? try unregistering your app from GCM using the unregister() method and wait few hours or even a couple of days so Google servers will be refreshed or alternatively change your app package name and you will see that it will work just fine. I hope you can find this notice useful.

Comment: Hi there. If you read my post I made it clear I've tested on a device that was "clean" never before used with any other extension whatsoever.